# External diff tool for Visual SourceSafe 2005

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I need to register an external application for doing my diffs/merges in SourceSafe 2005.  I am easily able to do this with SVN, wondering if VSS has a similar option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

tools --> options --> custom editors

Operation = File Difference

Comment: The fact that this is still getting upvotes depresses me, because it means people are still using this software.

Answer (score -1):

use WinMerge, i know a lot of people use that instead of the goofy built in diff/merge tool.